# Get the submit button from a form?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the submit button and hide it?

I have:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $(this :submit).hide();
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find()` method:

```
$(this).find(':submit').hide();
```